# Azure ssh connection from home

Tags: azure, ssh

I want to connect to a vm in the Azure cloud from home i.e. without a fixed IP. I have added the two security rules for network interface and NSG respectively to accept inbound connections on the ssh port 22 using the ipv4 address given by showip.net. This doesn't work and I get a connection time-out - I tried out ipv6 address as well. If I do the very same thing for another server (outside Azure), the very same procedure works. The native ip address for both my home computer and the virtual machine I use as alternative are IPv6.

So the question is - does my connection from home fail, because there is some sort of reverse lookup failing or what could be the other causes?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like most likely the issue is some weird NATing of your ISP - especially when IPv6 comes into play, it can often be a bit hard to find the actual external IP address that your requests are coming from. You can try different sites like whatsmyip.com etc to see if you find another one that you can add.

Apart from that, there are various things you could try:

- Use SSH from the Azure Cloud Shell (https://shell.azure.com)
- Use Azure Bastion to have a jump host in the same VNET
- Use a point-to-site VPN from your PC into your VNET

Comment: Thanks, I tried out whatsmyip.com and unfortunately it didn't give a different information.  I will go via that remote server I am using now.